# UITableViewCell UIImageView moves between different cells on the same table

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, uitableview, xamarin

When I scroll in my UITableView, the UIImageView subview of a single UITableViewCell moves between other cells.  It doesn't take long for this issue to occur.  Simply scrolling down to the bottom of the list will cause the reply indicator (UIImageView) to move between different cells.

Here is my custom table view class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Control for interacting with comments
/// </summary>
public sealed class CommentView : UITableView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes with a data source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Data source</param>
    /// <param name="useSeparators">Whether separators should be used between comments</param>
    public CommentView(UITableViewSource source, bool useSeparators)
    {
        AllowsSelection = true;
        SeparatorStyle = useSeparators ?
            UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine :
            UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        Source = source;
        RowHeight = AutomaticDimension;
        EstimatedRowHeight = 100;
    }
}
```

Here is the GetCell method in my data source:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the cell in the table view at the index given
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tableView">Table view to get cell from</param>
/// <param name="indexPath">Index to get cell at</param>
/// <returns>Cell at the index specified</returns>
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var comment = Data[indexPath.Row];
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellId) as CommentCell;

    // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
    cell.LineCount = CommentLineCount;
    cell.HasReplies = comment.Replies.Count > 0;
    cell.UpdateCell(comment);
    cell.DrawIndicator(comment);
    if (!comment.IsReply)
    {
        DrawAccessories(comment, cell);
    }
    cell.UpdateConstraints();

    return cell;
}
```

And here is the full 'CommentCell' class:

```
using App.Common.Models;
using App.iOS.Utilities;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

namespace App.iOS.Views.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom cell control for displaying a single comment
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class CommentCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        private const string CustomCommentCss =
            "<style>*{{font-family:{0};font-size:{1};color:{2};}}span{{font-
weight:600;}}</style>";
        private static readonly CGRect ReplyIconDimensions = new CGRect(6, 6, 12, 9);
        private readonly UILabel _authorLabel;
        private readonly UILabel _commentLabel;
        private readonly UILabel _dateLabel;
        private readonly UIFont _font;

    private UIView _indicator;
    private ReplyCountIndicatorView _replyCountIndicator;

    public CommentCell(IntPtr p) : base(p)
    {
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
        LayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

        var textColor = Globals.ColorDark;

        _font = UIFont.FromName(Globals.FontSanFranLight, Globals.FontSizeBody);
        _authorLabel = new UILabel
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName(Globals.FontSanFranSemiBold, Globals.FontSizeBody),
            Lines = 1,
            LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
            TextColor = textColor
        };
        _commentLabel = new UILabel
        {
            Font = _font,
            LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
            TextColor = textColor
        };
        _dateLabel = new UILabel
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName(Globals.FontSanFranLight, Globals.FontSizeSmall),
            TextColor = Globals.ColorDisabled
        };

        ContentView.AddSubviews(_authorLabel, _commentLabel, _dateLabel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets whether this cell has replies associated with it
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasReplies { private get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the number of lines in the comment field
    /// </summary>
    public int LineCount { set { _commentLabel.Lines = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the constraints of the subviews
    /// </summary>
    public override void UpdateConstraints()
    {
        base.UpdateConstraints();
        _authorLabel.SetContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);
        _commentLabel.SetContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);
        _dateLabel.SetContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);
        _replyCountIndicator?.SetContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);

        var leftMargin = AnnotationIndicator.Size.Width + 2 * Globals.MarginGrid;

        if (_replyCountIndicator != null && HasReplies)
        {
            ContentView.ConstrainLayout(() =>
                _authorLabel.Frame.Top == ContentView.Frame.Top + Globals.MarginGrid &&
                _authorLabel.Frame.Left == ContentView.Frame.Left + leftMargin &&
                _authorLabel.Frame.Right == ContentView.Frame.Right - Globals.MarginGrid &&

                _commentLabel.Frame.Top == _authorLabel.Frame.Bottom + Globals.MarginGrid / 4 &&
                _commentLabel.Frame.Left == _authorLabel.Frame.Left &&
                _commentLabel.Frame.Right == _authorLabel.Frame.Right &&

                _dateLabel.Frame.Top == _commentLabel.Frame.Bottom + Globals.MarginGrid / 4 &&
                _dateLabel.Frame.Left == _authorLabel.Frame.Left &&
                _dateLabel.Frame.Right == _authorLabel.Frame.Right &&

                _replyCountIndicator.Frame.Top == _dateLabel.Frame.Bottom + Globals.MarginGrid &&
                _replyCountIndicator.Frame.Left == _dateLabel.Frame.Left &&
                _replyCountIndicator.Frame.Width == Globals.SmallToolbarItemSize &&
                _replyCountIndicator.Frame.Height == Globals.SmallToolbarItemSize &&
                _replyCountIndicator.Frame.Bottom == ContentView.Frame.Bottom - Globals.MarginGrid);   
        }
        else
        {
            ContentView.ConstrainLayout(() =>
                _authorLabel.Frame.Top == ContentView.Frame.Top + Globals.MarginGrid &&
                _authorLabel.Frame.Left == ContentView.Frame.Left + leftMargin &&
                _authorLabel.Frame.Right == ContentView.Frame.Right - Globals.MarginGrid &&

                _commentLabel.Frame.Top == _authorLabel.Frame.Bottom + Globals.MarginGrid / 4 &&
                _commentLabel.Frame.Left == _authorLabel.Frame.Left &&
                _commentLabel.Frame.Right == _authorLabel.Frame.Right &&

                _dateLabel.Frame.Top == _commentLabel.Frame.Bottom + Globals.MarginGrid / 4 &&
                _dateLabel.Frame.Left == _authorLabel.Frame.Left &&
                _dateLabel.Frame.Right == _authorLabel.Frame.Right &&
                _dateLabel.Frame.Bottom == ContentView.Frame.Bottom - Globals.MarginGrid);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the contents of the cell
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comment">Comment to update cell for</param>
    public void UpdateCell(Comment comment)
    {
        // update the comment author
        _authorLabel.Text = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comment.CreatedByUser.FirstName) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comment.CreatedByUser.LastName) ?
                comment.CreatedByUser.Email :
                $"{comment.CreatedByUser.FirstName} {comment.CreatedByUser.LastName}";

        // update the text
        var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes { DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML };
        var nsError = new NSError();

        // TODO: This is where emoji rendering goes wrong
        var text = comment.Text.Insert(0, string.Format(CustomCommentCss,
            _font.FontDescriptor.Name, _font.PointSize,
            ColorConverter.ConvertToHex(_commentLabel.TextColor)));
        var mutableString = new NSMutableAttributedString(new NSAttributedString(
            text, attr, ref nsError));
        var mutableParagraph = new NSMutableParagraphStyle
        {
            Alignment = UITextAlignment.Left,
            LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation
        };
        mutableString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ParagraphStyle, mutableParagraph,
            new NSRange(0, mutableString.Length));
        mutableString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.StrokeColor, Globals.ColorDark,
            new NSRange(0, mutableString.Length));
        _commentLabel.AttributedText = mutableString;

        // update the timestamp
        var localTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(
            comment.LastModifiedDateTime).ToString("g");
        _dateLabel.Text = comment.LastModifiedDateTime == comment.CreatedDateTime ? 
            localTime : $"Modified {localTime}";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the appropriate type of indicator next to the author's name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comment">Comment to draw indicator for</param>
    public void DrawIndicator(Comment comment)
    {
        // if we've already drawn the indicator and 
        // the comment has no annotation associated with it
        _indicator?.RemoveFromSuperview();

        // if the comment havs an annotation associated with it,
        // draw the annotation indicator
        if (comment.Annotation != null)
        {
            _indicator = new AnnotationIndicator
            {
                Location = new CGPoint(Globals.MarginGrid, Globals.MarginGrid),
                Number = comment.Annotation.AnnotationNumber,
                FillColor = Color.FromHex(comment.Annotation.FillColorValue).ToUIColor(),
                TextColor = Color.FromHex(comment.Annotation.TextColorValue).ToUIColor()
            };
            ContentView.AddSubview(_indicator);
        }

        // otherwise, draw the general comment indicator
        else
        {
            var dim = comment.IsReply ? ReplyIconDimensions :
                new CGRect(0, 0, AnnotationIndicator.Size.Width, AnnotationIndicator.Size.Height);
            _indicator = new UIImageView
            {
                ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit,
                Frame = new CGRect(Globals.MarginGrid + dim.X, Globals.MarginGrid + dim.Y, dim.Width, dim.Height),
                Image = comment.IsReply ? UIImage.FromFile("reply.png") :
                    UIImage.FromFile("general_annotation_indicator.png")
            };
            ContentView.AddSubview(_indicator);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the reply count indicator
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comment">Comment to draw indicator for</param>
    public void DrawReplyCountIndicator(Comment comment)
    {
        if (_replyCountIndicator != null)
        {
            _replyCountIndicator.RemoveFromSuperview();
            _replyCountIndicator = null;
        }
        _replyCountIndicator = new ReplyCountIndicatorView(comment.Replies.Count);
        ContentView.AddSubview(_replyCountIndicator);
    }
}
}
```

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Normal]
[image: The reply indicator has now moved to another cell]

Answer (score 0):

DequeueReusableCell will return an already existing version of the cell from the cache.  It may already be populated with data from a prior use, so it is your responsibility to be sure that any data fields, etc, are reset properly to reflect the state of the current cell.

Comment: It looks like everything is reset properly except for the _replyCountIndicator.  Is there any wrong with the DrawReplyCountIndicator method in the CommentCell class?  Specifically the removal of the indicator:

Comment: if (_replyCountIndicator != null) {
    _replyCountIndicator.RemoveFromSuperview();
    _replyCountIndicator = null;}

Comment: you really need to step through it in the debugger to verify it's doing what you expect